# Python: Does an iteration through 'list[a:b]' first copy that part of the list (which could be expensive)?

Tags: python

When I iterate through the values of `list1` from `start` to `stop`, as in:

```
for value in list1[start:stop]:
    ....
```

Does python first copy that part of the list (as is done when doing `list2 = list1[:]`)? This could get  very expensive for large lists!

If it doesn't copy it in the above example, does that always hold true? I need to do the following sort of loop, very often, on large sections of (very) large lists:

```
for index, value in enumerate(list1[start:stop], start):
    ....
```

Comment: But does `list1` actually need to be a *list*? I think it would not result in any copy at all if `list1` were, e.g., a Numpy array.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe - No, as long as a Numpy array can handle tuples/integers/strings/sub'Numpy' arrays - i.e. a variety of differently sized data types. I don't know anything about numpy though, and the module 'array' shipped with python doesn't appear (in my cprofile tests) to make much difference, if any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list1[start:stop]` creates a new list, period. This is always the case, regardless of whether you're iterating over the result directly or have a function in between or use it in any other context (you'd need a moderately static language, or sophisticated type inference, to optimize even for simple instances of the first case).

Note that this is **independent from the iteration**! The iteration itself does not copy, and the list slicing copies even if you throw the result away.

It only copies pointers though, so if you're always taking very small sublists, you probably wouldn't notice any difference. If the sublists are larger, you could either iterate over indices (`[x]range`) or use `itertools.islice`. The latter would have to skip over `start` items first though, so you may pay a hefty time penality for the memory savings. The former is ugly, but most efficent *asymptomically*.

Comment: Is it a slow operation to repeatedly access high indices in large lists? In other words, do I benefit by doing `for index in range(start,stop): #do something with 'list[index]'` vs `for value in list[start:stop]: #do something with `value`?

Comment: @Jeff: [list access](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(1) worst-case, i.e. independent from the index and the size of the array. What Python calls a list is really just a dynamic, over-allocating array.

Comment: @Jeff: Why don't you just benchmark it? It's not that much of a hassle

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The expression `list1[start:stop]` creates a new list containing the elements in the specified range. However it isn't copying the actual data, just a bunch of pointers so unless the list is very long the overhead won't normally matter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking this question, you could have simply tested this with the magical ID method

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> id(x[1])   
4971620
>>> id(x[1:][0]) #same as the original list
4971620
>>> id(x[2:3])
44327400
>>> id(x)
44408224
>>>
```

`x[2:3]` actually creates a new list, but the elements are still referred to the original list.

Comment: *The items* are the same. The question is: Is a new list created? (Also, small integers are bad test data as they're cached and thus `[1, 2][0] is [0, 1][1]`)